# Set icons with ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, contextmenu

I have a context menu where the header, the command, and the icon are defined by the observablecollection "ContextMenuItems" in the Viewmodel.

```
<Window.ContextMenu >
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems}" >
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Titel}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Action}"/>
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

So far so good, the only Problem I have, is that only the Icon of the last MenuItem is visible. What am I doing wrong here?

I checked the other icons, they are all working as long as their entry is the last one in the contextmenu.